# Access to shared resource, lock unlock or wait notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

Scenario:

Multi-threads reading from different sources.
One single access point to a shared queue (See a class RiderSynchronized trying to write)
Every line a Reader reads, It tries to insert into a shared queue through method RiderSynchronized provides.

When shared queue is full, I have to run a batch on a prepared statement to insert into Oracle. Meanwhile, all access to shared queue it must be denied.

Code:

```
public class RiderSynchronized {

    private ArrayDeque<JSONRecord> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private OracleDAO oracleDao;
    private long capacity;

    public RiderSynchronized(OracleDAO oracleDao, long capacity) {
        this.oracleDao = oracleDao;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public synchronized boolean addRecord(JSONRecord record) {
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            while (queue.size() >= capacity) {
                wait();
            }

            queue.add(record);
            if (queue.size() < capacity) {
                success = true;
                notify(); //notify single Thread
            } else {
                JSONRecord currentRecord = null;
                while ((currentRecord = queue.poll()) != null) {
                    oracleDao.insertRowParsedIntoBatch(currentRecord);
                }
                oracleDao.runBatch();
                success = true;
                notifyAll(); //it could be all Reading Threads are waiting. Notify all

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

I have to admit I'm a little worried about a thing.

1) Reader threads can just use addRecord indistinctly? Are They going to wait for themselves? Or Do I have to implement some other method where to check before to run addRecord Method?

2) When queue.size < capacity, I decide to notify just to one thread, because IMHO, at this point, no threads should be in status waiting. Am I wrong? Should I notify All?

2b)  Exact question for the "else" statement. Is it a good practice to notifyAll? At this point, it could be all threds are waiting?

3) Finally. I'm a little concerned to re-write everything using Lock e Condition Classes. Is it a better decision? Or Is it ok how I'm running this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Reader threads can just use addRecord indistinctly? Are They going
>   to wait for themselves? Or Do I have to implement some other method
>   where to check before to run addRecord Method?

The problem with your current code is that if for some reason `notifyAll` is not called by the only thread that theoretically should be able to go into the `else` block then **your threads will wait forever**.

The potential risks in your code are:

- `oracleDao.insertRowParsedIntoBatch(currentRecord)`
- `oracleDao.runBatch()`

With your current code if one of those methods throw an exception `notifyAll` will never be called so **your threads will wait forever**, you should at least consider calling `notifyAll` in a `finally` block to make sure that it will be called whether happens.

---

> 2) When queue.size < capacity, I decide to notify just to one thread,
>   because IMHO, at this point, no threads should be in status waiting.
>   Am I wrong? Should I notify All?

Your threads could only wait in case `queue.size() >= capacity` so for me `notify` is not even needed as this condition (`queue.size() < capacity`) is not expected by any thread.

---

> 2b) Exact question for the "else" statement. Is it a good practice to
>   notifyAll? At this point, it could be all threds are waiting?

**Item 69 from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)**:

> A related issue is whether you should use `notify` or `notifyAll` to wake
>   waiting threads. (Recall that `notify` wakes a single waiting thread,
>   assuming such a thread exists, and `notifyAll` wakes all waiting
>   threads.) It is often said that you should always use `notifyAll`. This
>   is reasonable, conservative advice. It will always yield correct
>   results because it guarantees that you’ll wake the threads that need
>   to be awakened. You may wake some other threads, too, but this won’t
>   affect the correctness of your program. These threads will check the
>   condition for which they’re waiting and, finding it false, will
>   continue waiting. As an optimization, you may choose to invoke `notify`
>   instead of `notifyAll` if all threads that could be in the wait-set are
>   waiting for the same condition and only one thread at a time can
>   benefit from the condition becoming true. Even if these conditions
>   appear true, there may be cause to use `notifyAll` in place of notify.
>   Just as placing the wait invocation in a loop protects against
>   accidental or malicious notifications on a publicly accessible object,
>   using `notifyAll` in place of `notify` protects against accidental or
>   malicious waits by an unrelated thread. Such waits could otherwise
>   “*swallow*” a critical notification, leaving its intended recipient
>   waiting indefinitely.

---

> 3) Finally. I'm a little concerned to re-write everything using Lock e
>   Condition Classes. Is it a better decision? Or Is it ok how I'm
>   running this scenario?

`Lock` and `Condition` are interesting if you need features that are not available with intrinsic locks like for example `tryLock()` or the ability to awake only threads waiting for a given condition. In your case it doesn't seem to be necessary so you can keep it like it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer you question one by one.

1) If I understand you correctly answer is **yes** thread will wait and you don't need to do anything else.

2) You don't need to notify anyone in case of `queue.size < capacity` there are no waiting thread at this point.

3) **Yes** it is ok to notify all. If more threads than capacity is waiting rest of them come to `wait` state fast.

4) It is opinion based question. In your scenario you wont get any benefit from rewriting.